# redirect logger output to a textpane in java

Tags: java, swing, apache-commons-logging

how to redirect org.apache.commons.logging output to a JTextArea??

I successfully redirected sys.err and sys.out using MessageConsole. its working fine. but I am not getting log output in textarea

Comment: The Logging package is an ultra-thin bridge between different logging implementations. Which implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you know how to redirect standard streams where you want them, one possible action is to make a PrintWriter in your logger, redirect the PrintWriter to the MessageConsole, and have the logger print any output to the PrintWriter so it will get redirected.

Comment: System.out is a PrintWriter...and you redirected that, right?

Comment: yes... Just now got a idea, I guess, i need to change it in Log4j's Property file.... Will check it first, and post again....